# NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

i get this error when starting Nifi 1.9.2 in cluster mode with embedded zookeeper 3.5.5.

I successfully start three zookeeper 3.5.5 separately using Java 1.8.nifi.

```
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:935)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:158)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:72)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:297)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.apache.nifi.spring.StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.getObject(StandardFlowServiceFactoryBean.java:48)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:188)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.<init>(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:55)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.server.ZooKeeperStateServer.create(ZooKeeperStateServer.java:189)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.<init>(FlowController.java:576)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.createClusteredInstance(FlowController.java:399)
    at org.apache.nifi.spring.FlowControllerFactoryBean.getObject(FlowControllerFactoryBean.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
2019-08-03 11:13:17,902 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2019-08-03 11:13:17,982 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@1b07ba9{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{192.168.159.130:18001}
2019-08-03 11:13:17,991 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
```

This error took me too much time,but i could not reslove it.
Can someone help me?
THX in Advance.

**conf/zookeeper.properties**

```
clientPort=2187
#clientPort=2188
#clientPort=2189
server.1=machine001:3888:4888
server.2=machine001:5888:6888
server.3=machine001:7888:8888
```

**myid**

```
1
#2
#3
```

**conf/nifi.properties**

```
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
nifi.web.http.host=machine001 
nifi.web.http.port=8000
#nifi.web.http.port=8001
#nifi.web.http.port=8002

nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=machine001
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=9997
#nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=9998
#nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=9999

nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=machine001:2187,machine001:2188,machine001:2189
```

**conf/state-management.xml**

```
<property name="Connect String">machine001:2187,machine001:2188,machine001:2189</property>
```

Comment: How a do you bind the clientport to the different machines. I just saw the default port over there. Did you set it for each instance?

Comment: Only one machaine but with different prots.`[root@localhost bin]# ./zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /root/mycentos/zookeeper-1/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Client port found: xxx1. Client address: localhost.
Mode: follower
`#xxx2,#xxx3

Comment: I checked the documentation of zookeeper as well. The configuration looks fine to me. Except it doesn't show all required properties ticktime and datadir. Does it start with default configuration or does it read the correct config file. Looks like that it ignores the server which are set in the config. I would guess it doesn't read the config file. Sorry when I'm guessing, but this is the tricky part.

Comment: You said you start zookeepers separately, but is there a reason to set the option `nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true`?

Comment: hi,@Lamanus nifi.properties:```# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties```

Comment: @ManuelPolacek What config file are you talk?

Comment: Sorry. I meant the zookeeper.properties. is it in the same place where the application is expecting it? As I've said, the file itself looks fine. But somehow it's not loaded or at least not loaded correctly.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek Thank you.You make me understand how it works!

Comment: Happy to hear, that I could give you a hint.

Comment: Btw. please post the solution for your problem. Maybe others run into same problem. Then they know how to fix it.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek Sorry,i thought  i did what everyone else has done before,which is to click the answer.Your kindness will treat hair loss for many coders.BTW,I filled <property name="Connect String"> in state-management.xml,but idk how system loaded it.THK again.

Comment: Yes. Click the right answer is correct. I didn't realize you did. My fault... I'm just blind. :-P

Comment: @ManuelPolacek It's OK,you're warm.You know how system load state-management.xml?i just know if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start>is set to true,system will load zookeeper.properties for nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from ZooKeeper client code that parses the "server.XXX" entries in zookeeper.properts, and its trying to split the entry on ":" and get the parts at index 0 and index 1, and there is no index 1 so its getting array index out of bounds. This basically means one of your server entries is not of the form host:port or host:port:port.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if you are setting nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true then you shouldn't be starting your own ZooKeeper. You either use embdedded or external, but not both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.I sloved the problem because of your second part,but sometimes the third node can't connect.And i still wonder about your first part:which index are you indicating? 
**ZooKeeper.properties:**
` clientPort=2187server.1=machine001:3888:3888
server.2=machine001:5888:6888
server.3=machine001:7888:8888`

Comment: The first part is referring to one of the values for server.1, server.2, or server.3

Comment: So `clientPort=2187 server.1=machine001:3888:3888 `  would be split in two parts by Zookeeper client code:`server.1:machine001` and `3888:3888`? And what does it meant there is no index 1?Please you explain more.Really appreciate!